# how to write a set of local extrema formally

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is the following notation correct?

$X = \left\{x_t > \max\left(x_{t-z},\ldots,x_{t-1},x_{t+1},\ldots,x_{t+z}\right) \mid (t-z, \ldots, t+z)\in \mathbb{T}^{2z+1} ∧ k ∈ ℕ\setminus \{0\}\right\} $

where $\mathbb{T} = [1,T]\cap\mathbb{N}$ denotes the time periods over which $x$ runs.

I basically want to say that $X$ is the set of points that are local maxima in a neighbourhood of $z$ points to the right and left of each point. my query is that, for instance, for $z=3$ and $t=2$, the condition would actually be:

$x_2 > \max(x_1,x_3,x_4,x_5)$

and $(x_1,x_3,x_4,x_5)$ is not a point in the space $T^7$.

Maybe a better option would be to write $t-z,\ldots,t+z \in \mathbb{T}$ instead of $(t-z,\ldots,t+z) \in\mathbb{T}^{2z+1}$ ... but it still seems unclear to me.

Comment: maybe this: $\{x_{t}>max \bigcup_{j\neq t} x_{j}\in\mathbb{X}|\parallel x_{t}-x_{j}\parallel\leq z\}|(t,j)\in\mathbb{T}^{2}\wedge z\in\mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}\}$, where $\mathbb{T} = [1,T]\cap\mathbb{N}$  ? maybe the $\in\mathbb{X}$ is not even necessary..

Comment: It's quite messy...You may need to clarify the question. What is $x$? Is it a sequence indexed by natural numbers or a function defined on an interval?

Comment: yes, it is a sequence of real numbers indexed by natural numbers.

Comment: Then local maximum means: $x_{k}\geq x_{k-1} , x_{k}\geq x_{k+1}$.

Comment: it means $x_t$ larger than all z numbers to the right of it in the sequence and larger than all z numbers o the left. my problem is that in a sequence $\{x_1,x_2....,x_T\}$, there are no $x_0$,$x_{-1}$, $x_{T+1}$ etc

Comment: so while for $x_{10}$ the condition is simply $x_{10}>max(x_{11},x_{12},x_{13},x_{14},x_{15},x_9,x_8,x_7,x_6,x_5)$ for z=5, for $x_1$ is is just $x_1>max(x_2,...,x_6)$..the question is how to write a general expression that allows for this different behavior